# make byte[] property load lazy

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using **EF4 Code First** and I have a property:

```
public byte[] Bytes {get;set;}
```

can I make this property load lazily ( only when it's needed) ?

Answer (score 6):

Table spliting works in EF 4.1 RC:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ItemDetail ItemDetail { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemDetail> ItemDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Items");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemDetail>().ToTable("Items");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasRequired(i => i.ItemDetail)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed an old common request since EF 1, EF 4 and [still in EF 4.1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/adonetefx/thread/f59646ee-8139-4bc7-8421-2efdde85a10c).

The link is related to CTP5 and the only possible solution is **Table Splitting**. You basically need to define two entity classes but map them to one single table in the database. The task to load the byte[] is then reduced to loading a normal navigation property.

The answer in the post talks about a bug in CTP5 which made Table splitting not working correctly but which is hopefully fixed now in EF 4.1 RC (but I don't know if it's really fixed).