# EF4 and intentionally returning only *some* of the properties of an entity

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4

Folks, I know I didn't phrase that title very well, but here's the scenario.

I have a WinForm UI tier, and a WCF middle tier, serving up my EF4 entity objects, which are (of course) mapped to my database tables.  Everything works fine.

One of my objects is the Client - and in the Client db table are three varbinary(max) fields for PDF documents.  So my entity object has three Byte() properties, one for each document.

But when I load up an initial grid listing the Clients, it's going to drag ALL that PDF data from the MT - making a much bigger payload than I generally need.

With DataSets, I'd write my SQL to not include the PDF binary - but I'd include a Boolean flag field for each to indicate whether there IS one to download if the user wants it.  Then I'd load the PDFs via a separate call as needed.

With EF4 - what's the best pattern for this?

First, I'm thinking to put the documents into a child-table/child-objects, so I don't pull it across the tier with the Client.  One problem solved.

Second, I suppose I could use partial classes to extend my Client entity object to have the three Boolean properties I want.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have three options:

1) Create a custom class which you project the properties you want into:

```
public class MySpecialSelection
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // more
    public bool HasPDFDoc1 { get; set; }
    public bool HasPDFDoc2 { get; set; }
    public bool HasPDFDoc3 { get; set; }
}

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var mySpecialSelectionList = context.MyEntities.Where(...some predicate...)
        .Select(e => new MySpecialSelection
        {
            ID = e.ID,
            Name = e.Name,
            // ...
            HasPdfDoc1 = (e.PdfDoc1 != null),
            HasPdfDoc2 = (e.PdfDoc2 != null),
            HasPdfDoc3 = (e.PdfDoc3 != null),
        }).ToList();

    // ...
}
```

Instead of a "named" object you can also project into anonymous types.

Note: This doesn't attach any full model entity to the context, so you won't have any change tracking of entities.

2) Table splitting: It means that you split your single entity into two separate classes which are related by a navigation property. You can map then both entities to a single table in the database. It allows you to load the navigation properties (for instance the binary fields) on request (by lazy, eager or explicite loading). Details about this for EF4.0 are [here](http://www.deveducate.com/blog/post/2010/12/14/Entity-Framework-Modeling-Table-Splitting.aspx) and for EF4.1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582198/make-byte-property-load-lazy).

3) Your own proposal: Create separate tables and separate entities which are linked by navigation properties and FK constraints.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I hadn't thought about making two objects from one table.  Very neat idea.

Comment: Another option that came up was to set my three Byte() fields to nothing before sending them over WCF to the UI, but to add three ".Has" Boolean fields.  That way, the one object tells me whether it "has" each of the documents, but it doesn't include them in the payload.  When I need one in the UI, I'd pull it from the DB/MT via another call entirely.

Comment: And it turns out the client decided he doesn't need these documents in the database anyway!  Wahoo!  Still, Slauma, I bestow upon you the winner's laurels.