# EntityFramework: load a specific column on first access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I would like to use the EF6 or EFCore2. I have the problem that I want to load some columns/properties at the first access. This properties can be large and are only required in certain cases!

I have already searched for a solution and found this article: [make byte[] property load lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582198/make-byte-property-load-lazy)

Is there a better solution than "Table Splitting"? It would be nice to have a solution using Attributes ;-)

Or how would you solve that?

```cs
public class UserEntity
{
    public ulong Id {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public byte[] LargeData {get; set;} //Lazy Loading
}
```

**UPDATE:**

1. I have a WPF-Application with a list of users (class "UserEntity") (XAML-Binding)
2. Select one Item: Large data (like picture of the user) should load automatically from the database.
3. Next time I select the same user, the data does not need to be reloaded from database because it is cached.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: why don't you want to use table splitting? you can use this and with eager loading. every time when you need to `LargeData` include it.

Comment: Is there not an automatic way? For example with Attributes?

Comment: Why you can't just exclude this property from `select` statement?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov How would you implement automatic reload?

Comment: @IntOverflow you could make a wrapper of the user class which you then set all the properties except the large one and have that property a deferred load, which then accesses the database, cache via private field and fetch if null.